# accents misaligned in MATHASTEXT

Tags: fonts, mathastext

I am trying the package **MATHASTEXT with libertine font.** With the "italic" option.

The output seems fine, with an exception: the accents -- I use \tilde and \bar -- are misaligned horizontally (too much to the left).

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\begin{document}
The trouble is with $\backslash$\verb|tilde| and $\backslash$\verb|bar|. The 
position is not centered correctly above the letters:
\[ \tilde{A} \tilde{B} \bar{A} \bar{B} \]
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help,

Amnon

Comment: Welcome! I think things are coming from different fonts and the results are predictably poor.

Comment: to @cfr: I was looking for a workaround for the NEWTXMATH problem. Now that that is solved (thanks to you), I don't think I will need MATHASTEXT.

Answer (score 3):

#### warning (Nov., 2018)

please note that this answer is a bit senseless as it uses mathastext mechanism to add extra spacing (fine to fix issues with letter `f` colliding with a `(` for example), here necessarily negative spacing, only to fix the accent placement, but clearly this ruins positioning with respect to binary operators etc..

As @Skillmon's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459614/4686) addresses this issue much more seriously, please don't pay attention to this one.

---

<strike>With version `1.3a of 2013/09/04` or later of [mathastext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext), you can do this:</strike>

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\begin{document}
The trouble is with $\backslash$\verb|tilde| and $\backslash$\verb|bar|. The 
position is not centered correctly above the letters:
\[ \tilde{A} \tilde{B} \bar{A} \bar{B} \]

Try the following:

\makeatletter
\@for\@tempa:=A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z\do{%
\MTsetmathskips{\@tempa}{-2mu}{2mu}}%
\makeatother


\[ \tilde{A} \tilde{B} \bar{A} \bar{B} \]


\[ \tilde{A}_{ij}^C + \bar{U}\bar{V}\cdot\tilde{B}^{\bar{A}*\bar{B} }\]

\[ \sum_{i=0}^\infty \tilde{A}_i^2\bar{C}^3\]

Read the \texttt{mathastext} documentation for more about
\texttt{\textbackslash MTsetmathskips}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: output of mathastext]

Comment: the image suggests to use `\MTsetmathskips` for lowercase letters too, like `i`.

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't move the accent but the characters. So you also kill the spacing of binary operators etc.

Comment: @Skillmon right. Perhaps I thought only some letters like `f` were troublesome and the shift might be good in other contexts. But one could perhaps limit the scope to when `\mathaccentV` is used, is this what you do, or something altogether distinct from the mathastext letter skips (perhaps you move the accent rather)? (I have not read yet your answer in detail). I feel I should delete mine. (as obviously it is not good as it does not  limitin the scope to accented letters)

Comment: (I think I did not improve my answer because OP said in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271546/accents-misaligned-in-mathastext/271623?noredirect=1#comment652345_271575) he did not need mathastext anymore)

Comment: Mine hacks `\mathaccentV` and then does something like `\hat{A\mkern4mu}\mkern-4mu` which effectively only moves the accents, but only does so for specific arguments of `\hat`, etc..

Comment: @Skillmon answer updated to send the flood of upvotes to yours...

Comment: I can already feel the 150k rep I'll get from this...

Comment: @Skillmon  With Great Power Comes Great Responsibility: your turn now!

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a package initially for a template I created for the chair I wrote my Bachelor's thesis at. The package loads `amsmath` and works by redefining `\mathaccentV`, which is used internally by `amsmath` in the macros `\hat`, `\check`, `\tilde`, `\acute`, `\grave`, `\dot`, `\ddot`, `\breve`, `\bar`, `\vec` and `\mathring`.

It has two modes from which you can choose during load time. The first moves the accents based on the height of the used box. The second has a list of arguments for which shift widths are defined. The first is quick and dirty and the result is always a compromise of best fit for all, while the second needs more work (you'll have to define a shift for each character you'll use once). For the list approach there is a definition list included for the font combination `\usepackage{helvet}\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}\usepackage[italic,defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}`.

Both versions have a way to force or prevent the displacement. If you're using `height` you can enforce it with a `*` after e.g. `\hat`, a `!` does prevent it. With `height` the displacement is only applied automatically if the argument is a single token with category code 11.

If you're using the `list` option, you can specify the used displacement in mu inside an optional argument (e.g. `\hat[4mu]{a}`) or you can use a known argument inside the optional argument (so using the defined shift of `B` for `A` with `\hat[B]{A}`).

Unfortunately the package is not published to CTAN and therefore not included in any TeX distribution. You can find it here: https://gitlass.de/jonathan/MRTbundle/src/branch/master/MRTsfacc (you'll also need [MRTif](https://gitlass.de/jonathan/MRTbundle/src/branch/master/MRTif) and [MRTutil](https://gitlass.de/jonathan/MRTbundle/src/branch/master/MRTutil)).

Documentation is contained in the following PDF in chapter 8 (the documentation is one PDF for each class and package contained in that bundle): https://gitlass.de/jonathan/MRTbundle/src/branch/master/Doc/doc_MRTbundle.pdf

Usage example using the `height` mode:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
% move based on height, the horizontal displacement is <share>*<height>, <share> defaults to 0.25
\usepackage[height]{MRTsfacc}
\begin{document}
The trouble is with $\backslash$\verb|tilde| and $\backslash$\verb|bar|. The 
position is not centered correctly above the letters:
\[ \tilde{A} \tilde{B} \bar{A} \bar{B} \]

Every character in a-zA-Z with {\textbackslash\verb|hat|}:

\parbox{.4\linewidth}
  {%
    $\hat{a}$$\hat{A}$
    $\hat{b}$$\hat{B}$
    $\hat{c}$$\hat{C}$
    $\hat{d}$$\hat{D}$
    $\hat{e}$$\hat{E}$
    $\hat{f}$$\hat{F}$
    $\hat{g}$$\hat{G}$
    $\hat{h}$$\hat{H}$
    $\hat{i}$$\hat{I}$
    $\hat{j}$$\hat{J}$
    $\hat{k}$$\hat{K}$
    $\hat{l}$$\hat{L}$
    $\hat{m}$$\hat{M}$
    $\hat{n}$$\hat{N}$
    $\hat{o}$$\hat{O}$
    $\hat{p}$$\hat{P}$
    $\hat{q}$$\hat{Q}$
    $\hat{r}$$\hat{R}$
    $\hat{s}$$\hat{S}$
    $\hat{t}$$\hat{T}$
    $\hat{u}$$\hat{U}$
    $\hat{v}$$\hat{V}$
    $\hat{w}$$\hat{W}$
    $\hat{x}$$\hat{X}$
    $\hat{y}$$\hat{Y}$
    $\hat{z}$$\hat{Z}$
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Usage example using the `list` mode:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\usepackage[list]{MRTsfacc}
% I'm lazy so I only define shifts for `A` and `B`
\MRTsfaccShift{A}{4mu}
\MRTsfaccShift{B}{2.5mu}
\begin{document}
The trouble is with $\backslash$\verb|tilde| and $\backslash$\verb|bar|. The 
position is not centered correctly above the letters:
\[ \tilde{A} \tilde{B} \bar{A} \bar{B} \]

Every character in a-zA-Z with {\textbackslash\verb|hat|}:

\parbox{.4\linewidth}
  {%
    $\hat{a}$$\hat{A}$
    $\hat{b}$$\hat{B}$
    $\hat{c}$$\hat{C}$
    $\hat{d}$$\hat{D}$
    $\hat{e}$$\hat{E}$
    $\hat{f}$$\hat{F}$
    $\hat{g}$$\hat{G}$
    $\hat{h}$$\hat{H}$
    $\hat{i}$$\hat{I}$
    $\hat{j}$$\hat{J}$
    $\hat{k}$$\hat{K}$
    $\hat{l}$$\hat{L}$
    $\hat{m}$$\hat{M}$
    $\hat{n}$$\hat{N}$
    $\hat{o}$$\hat{O}$
    $\hat{p}$$\hat{P}$
    $\hat{q}$$\hat{Q}$
    $\hat{r}$$\hat{R}$
    $\hat{s}$$\hat{S}$
    $\hat{t}$$\hat{T}$
    $\hat{u}$$\hat{U}$
    $\hat{v}$$\hat{V}$
    $\hat{w}$$\hat{W}$
    $\hat{x}$$\hat{X}$
    $\hat{y}$$\hat{Y}$
    $\hat{z}$$\hat{Z}$
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Currently mathastext works also with unicode-math, where you want to pick some math font, but then use your text font for letters and numbers. Is your approach also OK here? I cannot seem able to make it work in this case...

Comment: @Callegar I never tested it there, so am not sure. I wrote that package for a specific template I maintain. I'll take a quick look, but can't promise anything (and I don't think I will update the package code just to make it compatible with `unicode-math`, as I said, it is only written for a specific template -- never say never)

Comment: @Callegar I'm sorry, but it seems there is no chance to make the two compatible. `unicode-math` changes the definition of `\hat` etc. to not use `\mathaccentV` but instead `\Umathaccent` which is a primitive in LuaTeX and XeTeX. So the hack used by `MRTsfacc` can't apply.

Comment: thanks for the explanation about `\Umathaccent`. Do you think that in this case, it may be possible to redefine `\hat` and friends back to something not using `\Umathaccent` to give you a reasonably positioned accent in this case?

Comment: @Callegar this could be possible, but I have no idea whether you'd break other things with this (I really don't have any experience with `unicode-math`...). Take a look at the definitions done by `amsmath` and restore them, then check whether these work. It would be possible to hack `MRTsfacc` as well, to fall back to `\Umathaccent` instead of just not applying any shift. But that could be quite some work for which I currently don't have the time.

Comment: @Skillmon Based on your suggestion, I'm trying to work with the package `MRTsfacc`, but it requires `MRTutil` and `MRTif` style files, please suggest from where I can get these?

Comment: @MadyYuvi from the same repository ([MRTif](https://gitlass.de/jonathan/MRTbundle/src/branch/master/MRTif) and [MRTutil](https://gitlass.de/jonathan/MRTbundle/src/branch/master/MRTutil)).

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks, I'll check and get back....

Answer (score 2):

Here. I define alt versions of `\bar` and `\tilde` using stacks, that work across math styles.  In the MWE, I show the original version on the left of each pair, and the alt version on the right of each pair.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\stackMath
\newcommand\alttilde[1]{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackon[\dimexpr-.5pt-4\LMpt]{\SavedStyle#1}{%
  \SavedStyle\kern.30\ht0\tilde{}}}}
\newcommand\altbar[1]{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackon[\dimexpr-1.0pt-3.3\LMpt]{\SavedStyle#1}{%
  \SavedStyle\kern.30\ht0\bar{}}}}
\begin{document}
\def\tmp{\tilde{A} \alttilde{A} \quad
 \tilde{B} \alttilde{B}\quad
 \tilde{c} \alttilde{c}\quad
 \bar{A} \altbar{A}\quad
 \bar{B} \altbar{B}\quad
  \bar{c} \altbar{c}}
\[ \tmp \]
\[ \scriptstyle \tmp \]
\[ \scriptscriptstyle \tmp \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: to @StevenBSegletes: Thanks for the code. I tried to run it on my machine, but some packages were missing. Since I can get NEWTXMATH working now, I will not require MATHASTEXT in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `mathastext` in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can load Libertinus Math with `unicode-math` (or through `\usepackage{libertinus}` or `\usepackage[libertinus]{fontsetup}`, either of which will do that for you).

In PDFLaTeX, you can `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`.

Finally, you can load the legacy Libertine-based math font from the above with `\DeclareMathAlphabet` or the `isomath` package.  It’s the the `nxlmi` family, and has the OML encoding (with both Latin and Greek letters).